# Grunt not being found when installing grunt-sass with Node.js via Git Bash on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, sass, gruntjs

I am following a course on Lynda.com on using Node.js to download packages etc. 
I have followed the instructions completely.
I have installed the latest version of Node.js,

Via Git Bash I have installed the latest version of Grunt as follows

```
Nicholas@NicksDesktop MINGW64 /
$ npm install -g grunt cli
C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt -> C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt\bin\grunt
C:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- cli@1.0.1
`-- grunt@1.0.1
```

When I enter the following via Git Bash
`npm install --save grunt-sass`
I get the following error

```
npm WARN grunt-sass@2.0.0 requires a peer of grunt@>=0.4.0 but none was installed.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have entered 'npm  list' into Git Bash and get this error 'npm ERR! peer dep missing: grunt@>=0.4.0, required by grunt-sass@2.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

I navigated to the folder where grunt-sass is installed via Git Bash and then entered

```
npm install grunt@0.4.0
```

This seems to fix the errors, it seems that after this both a up to date version are installed and the required older version.